# How to compress by removing duplicates in python?

Tags: python, string, compression, whitespace

I have strings with blocks of the same character in, eg '1254,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,982'. What I'm aiming to do is replace that with something along the lines of '1254(,16)982' so that the original string can be reconstructed. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for [run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding): here is a Python implementation based loosely on [this one](http://wordaligned.org/articles/runlength-encoding-in-python).

```
import itertools

def runlength_enc(s):
    '''Return a run-length encoded version of the string'''
    enc = ((x, sum(1 for _ in gp)) for x, gp in itertools.groupby(s))
    removed_1s = [((c, n) if n > 1 else c) for c, n in enc]
    joined = [["".join(g)] if n == 1 else list(g)
                    for n, g in itertools.groupby(removed_1s, key=len)]
    return list(itertools.chain(*joined))

def runlength_decode(enc):
    return "".join((c[0] * c[1] if len(c) == 2 else c) for c in enc)
```

For your example:

```
print runlength_enc("1254,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,982")
# ['1254', (',', 16), '982']
print runlength_decode(runlength_enc("1254,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,982"))
# 1254,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,982
```

(Note that this will be efficient only if there are very long runs in your string).

Comment: I don't usually advocate in-homogonous lists, but having `('1',1)` seems a little redundant when you could just have `'1'`.  I think you could pretty easily modify this to return `['1254',(',',16),'982']`.  In terms of memory usage (and possibly disk usage), this would be a lot more efficient (1 list, 1 tuple, 4 strings, 1 int) instead of your version which has 1 list, 8 tuples, 8 strings, 8 ints.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the exact compressed form you may want to look at `zlib.compress` and `zlib.decompress`. `zlib`is a standard Python library that can compress a single string and will probably get better compression than a self implemented compression algorithm.

Comment: zlib is getting kind of long in the tooth.  bz2 frequently compresses harder, and is still in the standard library.  xz/lzma is catching on, but I believe it didn't make the standard library until Python 3.3 - however, it's available as a 3rd party library for older Python's.

Answer (score 1):

using regular expressions:

```
s = '1254,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,982'

import re
c = re.sub(r'(.)\1+', lambda m: '(%s%d)' % (m.group(1), len(m.group(0))), s)
print c # 1254(,16)982
```

using itertools

```
import itertools
c = ''
for chr, g in itertools.groupby(s):
    k = len(list(g))
    c += chr if k == 1 else '(%s%d)' % (chr, k)
print c # 1254(,16)982
```